# "error":"Unsupported Media Type","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException"

Tags: spring-boot

I am using spring boot 1.3.0. I want to create a rest endpoint which procduces content of type "application/hal+json".

I am getting an "Unsupported Media Type" exception. Is this mediatype in not supported in spring boot 1.3.0

Can anyone let me know in which spring boot version it is supported?

I am using Gradle.
@RequestMapping(value = Array("/grouping"), consumes = Array(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE), produces = Array(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, "application/hal+json"), method = Array(RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.DELETE)) def processGroupingGetDelRequest(request: HttpServletRequest): ResponseEntity[Object] = {}

My Gradle file
dependencies {
    // This is the path to where fortify is installed on the Jenkins machine. To run local swap the lines.
    fortify fileTree(dir: '/opt/HP_Fortify/HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_4.21/Core/lib', include: '*.jar')
    //fortify fileTree(dir: 'C:/Program Files/HP_Fortify/HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_4.21/Core/lib/', include: '*.jar')

```
compile group:  'org.springframework',            name: 'spring-mock', version: '2.0.8'
    compile group: 'org.scala-lang',                   name: 'scala-library',                version: '2.11.7'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot',         name: 'spring-boot-starter-web',      version: '1.3.3.RELEASE'

/* the following pulls in: spring-orm, hibernate-entity-manager, spring-data-jpa: */
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.3.0.RELEASE') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.tomcat', module: 'tomcat-jdbc'
}
compile('com.zaxxer:HikariCP:2.6.1') {
    exclude group: 'org.hibernate', module: 'hibernate-core'
}


/* the following pulls in: spring-jdbc, spring-tx, tomcat-jdbc:                               */
/* See:  http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html */
/* You need a dependency on spring-jdbc for an embedded database to be auto-configured.       */
/* It�s pulled in transitively via spring-boot-starter-data-jpa.                              */
// compile group: 'org.springframework.boot',         name:'spring-boot-starter-jdbc'

compile group: 'org.springframework.boot',         name: 'spring-boot-starter-security', version: '1.3.0.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot',         name: 'spring-boot-starter-log4j2',   version: '1.3.0.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework',              name: 'spring-jms',                   version: '4.2.3.RELEASE'

compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat', name: 'jackson-dataformat-yaml',      version: '2.8.6'
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module',     name: 'jackson-module-scala_2.11',    version: '2.8.6'


compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.core', name: 'jersey-common', version: '2.22.1'
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.core',        name: 'jersey-client',                version: '2.22.1'
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.media',       name: 'jersey-media-json-jackson',    version: '2.22.1'
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged', name: 'jersey-guava', version: '2.22.1'

compile group: 'org.springframework.security',     name: 'spring-security-ldap',         version: '4.2.1.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.security',     name: 'spring-security-core',         version: '4.2.1.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.security',     name: 'spring-security-config',       version: '4.2.1.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.security',     name: 'spring-security-web',          version: '4.2.1.RELEASE'

compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version:'2.8.6'
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version:'2.8.6'
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version:'2.8.6'
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module', name: 'jackson-module-jaxb-annotations', version: '2.8.6'
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs', name: 'jackson-jaxrs-base', version:'2.8.6'
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs', name: 'jackson-jaxrs-json-provider', version:'2.8.6'
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module', name: 'jackson-module-paranamer', version: '2.8.6'

// compile group: 'org.hibernate',                    name: 'hibernate-jpamodelgen'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/play-json_2.11
compile group: 'com.typesafe.play', name: 'play-json_2.11', version: '2.3.10'

providedCompile group: 'com.h2database',           name: 'h2',                           version: '1.4.196'
providedCompile group: 'org.apache.activemq',      name: 'activemq-broker',              version: '5.12.1'


providedRuntime group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat',   version: '1.3.0.RELEASE'

//Note: Un-comment if in Development the tomcat dependencies are not resolved during the spring boot runs
//providedRuntime group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', name: 'tomcat-embed-core', version: '8.5.11'

scoverage 'org.scoverage:scalac-scoverage-plugin_2.11:1.1.1', 'org.scoverage:scalac-scoverage-runtime_2.11:1.1.1'

testCompile group: 'junit',                        name: 'junit',                        version: '4.11'
testCompile group: 'org.scalatest',                name: 'scalatest_2.11',               version: '2+'
testCompile group: 'org.mockito',                  name: 'mockito-all',                  version: '1.10.19'
testCompile group: 'org.springframework',          name: 'spring-test',                  version:'4.2.3.RELEASE'


testRuntime 'org.pegdown:pegdown:1.1.0'
```

}

My Controller class

@RequestMapping(value = Array("/grouping"), consumes = Array(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE), produces = Array(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, "application/hal+json"), method = Array(RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.DELETE))
  def processGroupingGetDelRequest(request: HttpServletRequest): ResponseEntity[Object] = {

```
val requestDetails = extractRequestInformation(request)

val response = Service.processGroupingRequest(requestDetails.uri, requestDetails.httpMethod, requestDetails.queryParameters, "")
new ResponseEntity[Object](response, HttpStatus.OK)
```

}

Comment: Please post your whole code also `pom.xml`

Comment: Can you post your controller class please ?